# Facebook Graph API: What is the access token used?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to access a status/photo summary of a facebook Post. I attempted to use graph explorer tool to get the summary, which is successful.

Now what happens is I have an app, which has the same permissions I've given to the graph explorer tool (user_status, user_photos). I then build a URL like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}?access_token={my_app_access_token}

The access token I'm using is obtained from this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/), but all I get is an error. Am I using a wrong access token? If I am, how should I be getting the correct access token?

Comment: Those token don’t include any additional permissions. You will have to send your user through the login flow and ask for permissions while doing so – go read the docs on that.

Comment: Yes, I have already added the required permissions to my app, namely user_status and user_photos, and reauthorised my test account to provide the mentioned permissions. The question here is, what access token am I looking at? A per-session-user access token? Or my app token?